# How can I solve the targetdkversion and API problem?

Tags: android, api, sdk, version

In my application I have to use some code snippets like "canvas.save(), canvas.restore(), createdscaledBitmap" that I have to targetsdkversion=API27. I can't use them while targetsdkversion= API30, I researched and needed to use API27 and now I'm using API27. My question is, if I install GOOGLE PLAY STORE as targetsdkversion=API27, will it work on a device with API32?

Answer (score 0):

when you mark with targetsdkversion=x, any device with equal or higher Android version than x will work fine, devices with lower version may have unknown behavior, or error.
You should also set  android:minSdkVersion in AndroidManfiest.xml to x to prevent lower version devices from downloading your app.

Comment: for example, minsdkversion=16, targetsdkversion=27, then my app, API 16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32, Does it work on all versions?

Comment: Any device newer than or same as 27 will behave as you tested, any device lower than 27  may have a different behavior. You have to read the API documentation for the annotated API to understand the behavior for older devices.  Based on your minsdkversion, devices lower than 16 wouldn't be able to download at all.